# Take maximum value from a column and extract all lines with at least 20% of this value

Tags: linux, shell-script, awk

I would like to find the maximum value of column B **AND** keep all lines where column B values are 20% or more of the maximum.

**INPUT DATA**

```
A B C D E
2 79 56 SD L
1 09 67 JK S
9 60 37 KD G
0 10 47 SO E
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
A B C D E
2 79 56 SD L
9 60 37 KD G
```

I have tried using `awk 'BEGIN {max = 0} {if ($2>max) max=$2} END {if ($2 >= (0.1*max)) print}' file_in > file_out` but this only prints out what seems to be the last line of my file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save all the lines in an array to be able to go through them again at the `END{ }`. Or, alternatively, scan through the file twice. So, saving all the values and lines:

```
awk 'NR == 1 {header=$0; next}            # save the header            
  { lines[NR]  = $0; values[NR] = $2;     # save the line and 2nd field
    if ($2 > max) max = $2; }             # update max

  END { print header;                     # in the end, print the header
        for (i = 1 ; i <= NR ; i++)  {    # (we skipped line 0)
          if (values[i] >= max * 0.2)     # print lines where $2 was high enough
            print lines[i]; } } ' file_in
```

Answer (score 0):

With [miller](http://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/index.html):

1) Pretty-print data:

```
$> mlr --from data --ipprint --otsv cat
A   B   C   D   E
2   79  56  SD  L
9   60  37  KD  G
```

2) Add maximum of field `B` to field `B_max`:

```
$> mlr --from data --ipprint --otsv stats1 -a max -f B -s -F
A   B   C   D   E   B_max
2   79  56  SD  L   79.000000
1   09  67  JK  S   79.000000
9   60  37  KD  G   79.000000
0   10  47  SO  E   79.000000
```

3) Filter lines where `B >= B_max * 0.2`:

```
$> mlr --from data --ipprint --otsv stats1 -a max -f B -s -F then filter '$B >= $B_max*0.2'
A   B   C   D   E   B_max
2   79  56  SD  L   79.000000
9   60  37  KD  G   79.000000
```

4) Then `cut` away `B_max` again:

```
$> mlr --from data --ipprint --otsv stats1 -a max -f B -s -F then filter '$B >= $B_max*0.2' then cut -x -f B_max
A   B   C   D   E
2   79  56  SD  L
9   60  37  KD  G
```